# Convert tuple of tuples to a dictionary with key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have the following tuple of tuples:

```
tuples=((32, 'Network architectures', 5), (33, 'Network protocols', 5))
```

How could I turn it into a list of dictionary like this

```
dict=[ {"id": 32, "name": "Network architectures", "parent_id": 5}, {"id": 33, "name": "Network protocols", "parent_id": 5}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a list comprehension as follows. First create a list of keys which will repeat for all the tuples. Then just use `zip` to create individual dictionaries.

```
tuples=((32, 'Network architectures', 5), (33, 'Network protocols', 5))

keys = ["id", "name", "parent_id"]

answer = [{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, tup)} for tup in tuples]
# [{'id': 32, 'name': 'Network architectures', 'parent_id': 5},
#  {'id': 33, 'name': 'Network protocols', 'parent_id': 5}]
```

Comment: More general than what I have, nice.

Comment: @Cleb: Thanks. Although I have an extra for loop but in cases of large number of keys, it would not be a good idea to hardcode all the indices

Comment: @Sheldore. Thanks for the answer. I've implemented your code, but when I use print(answer) it return like this ```[{'parent_id': 5, 'id': 32, 'name': 'Network architectures'},....]```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[{'id': t[0], 'name': t[1], 'parent_id': t[2]} for t in tuples]
```

which gives:

```
[{'id': 32, 'name': 'Network architectures', 'parent_id': 5},
 {'id': 33, 'name': 'Network protocols', 'parent_id': 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `lambda` function

```
tuples=((32, 'Network architectures', 5), (33, 'Network protocols', 5))
dicts = list(map(lambda x:{'id':x[0],'name':x[1], 'parent_id':x[2]}, tuples))
print(dicts)
```

output

```
[ {"id": 32, "name": "Network architectures", "parent_id": 5}, {"id": 33, "name": "Network protocols", "parent_id": 5}]
```